# Cordova iOS app fixed header disappears on scroll but not on mobile Safari

Tags: ios, cordova, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have built an application for iOS, Android and the Web using Vuetify Cordova.  The app builds out fine, I can view it perfectly on the web on any browser and on Android. But on an iOS device as an app I get a glitch where the fixed position navigation header disappears on what seems to be a fast scroll, then reappears when scrolling stops.  If I use safari on the iPhone to view the web version it works perfectly without this problem, so just wondering if anyone else has come across (or managed to fix) this problem.

I have seen other question where safari was playing up, which is not my problem.

This is the structure of my main `App.vue` which then loads subsequent pages through `vue-router`

```
<v-app light>
    <v-content>
        <top-navigation :is-authenticated="isAuthenticated">
            <span slot="title"
                  class="heading heading-lg text-secondary"><strong>{{$route.meta.title}}</strong></span>
        </top-navigation>
        <div class="main-content">
            <router-view :key="$route.fullPath">
            </router-view>
        </div>
        <bottom-navigation :is-authenticated="isAuthenticated"></bottom-navigation>
    </v-content>
</v-app>
```

This is my `top-navigation` component

```
<div>
    <v-toolbar v-if="isAuthenticated"
        app
        dark
        flat
        :clipped-right="true"
        class="primary top-nav">
        <!-- Toolbar Navigation Content Here -->
    </v-toolbar>
</div>
```

Originally, this also had the `fixed` attribute on it as well, but I have since taken this out but it is still fixed to the top (which is the functionality I want).

There are other things on the page like a nav drawer, and some button in the toolbar etc, but I believe the error is because the toolbar is fixed, from what I've read online.

I can't see / work out the best way to resolve this glitch.

**UPDATE**

I've discovered this is not a `position:fixed` issue since I changed it to `position:absolute` for testing and although the nav bar now srolls up and dow the page, it is still disappearing on fast scroll.

**UPDATE 14/05/2018**
Pretty sure this is not a `position` issue at all, but a 
`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` problem.  I am using this css rule in a couple of places in my app to scroll a carousel horizontally (a bit like the videos on netflix / amazon etc) which is causing the error.  Not entirely sure of the fix yet.